# "foreach" package in R not working properly with "ff" package

Tags: r, foreach

I am working on data in R with 18M records. My computer does not have a wealth of RAM available, so I am trying the "ff" package to compensate. To make the amount of time reasonable, I am also using the "foreach" package and running the job in parallel. I am having issues when I run "foreach" in parallel with the full data; smaller groups of the data (say first 100K rows) run correctly.

What I am trying to obtain is rolling daily averages for peoples' values based on dates. I want the average daily value for past 7, 28, 91, etc. days. I am relatively new to R, so I do not understand its nuances. When I run this on the full data it stops after an hour and gives the error:

Task 1 failed - object 'PersonID' not found

What can I do to appropriately use the "ff" package with the "foreach" package. Also, it would be great if there were some way to output the data in a ff data frame and then into SQL. The code is below:

```
library("ff")
library("ffbase")
library("RODBC")
myconn <- odbcConnect("NO SHOW")
data <- as.ffdf(sqlFetch(myconn, "NO SHOW"))
#data[data=="NULL"] <- NA
#persons <- unique(data$PersonID, incomparables=FALSE)
persons <- aggregate(Value ~ PersonID, data=data, FUN=length)$PersonID

rollingLength <- 7
rollingTimes <- c(7,28,91,182,364,728,100000000)
valueCol <- 6
sinceCol <- 4

func <- function(stuff,id) {

check <- subset(stuff, PersonID == id)

tempvalue <- data.frame(matrix(,nrow=nrow(check),ncol=7,byrow=TRUE))

colnames(tempvalue) <- c("value7","value28","value91","value182","value364","value728","valueLTD")

tempvalue[1,] <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
rollingTrips <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
rollingSinceLast <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
startIndex <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
rollingvalues <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
rollingvalues[1:rollingLength] <- check[1,valueCol]

if (nrow(check) > 1) {

for (r in 2:nrow(check)) {

    tempvalue[r,] <- rollingvalues / rollingTrips
    rollingvalues <- rollingvalues + check[r,valueCol]
    rollingTrips <- rollingTrips + 1
    rollingSinceLast <- rollingSinceLast + ifelse(is.na(check[r,sinceCol]), 0, check[r,sinceCol])

    for (c in 1:(rollingLength-1)) {

        while (rollingSinceLast[c] >= rollingTimes[c]) {
            rollingvalues[c] <- rollingvalues[c] - check[startIndex[c],valueCol]
            rollingTrips[c] <- rollingTrips[c] - 1
            rollingSinceLast[c] <- rollingSinceLast[c] - check[startIndex[c]+1,sinceCol]
            startIndex[c] <- startIndex[c] + 1
        }

    }

}

}

return (cbind(check, tempvalue))

}

library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

cl<-makeCluster(12)
registerDoParallel(cl)

strt<-Sys.time()
outdata <- foreach(id=persons, .combine="rbind", .packages="ff") %dopar% func(data,id)
print(Sys.time()-strt)

stopCluster(cl)

sqlSave(myconn, outdata)
odbcClose(myconn)
```

Comment: What OS are you using? `foreach` behaves different on Windows than on Linux and OS X? Also, what version of R are you running and what version of the packages are you using? I don't know the answer to your question, but this information would be helpful for others trying to figure out your problem.

Comment: Running Windows 7 64-bit
R 3.1.0 64-bit

Comment: RODBC under 3.1.1;
foreach under 3.1.2;
ff under 3.1.2;
bit under 3.1.2;
doParallel under 3.1.2;
iterators under 3.1.2

Answer (score 3):

`foreach` package's `%dopar%` command need boundaries of a key value. 
You can simply split your `personID`. Also, you sholud set the `partition` value less than `makeCluster()`. If you don't do that, you got `file.access(filename, 0) == 0 is not TRUE` massage. Because, you can not access to pre-saved `ff` package file on the same cluster.

split `personID` example:

```
split_min<-min(persons$personID)
split_max<-max(persons$personID)
partition<-12  # "partition < cluster" is good.
quart_half<-floor((split_max-split_min)/partition)
split_num<-matrix(0,partition,2)
split_num[1,1]<-split_min
split_num[1,2]<-quart_half+split_min
if(partition>=3){
for(i in 2:(partition-1)){
  split_num[i,1]<-split_num[i-1,2]+1
  split_num[i,2]<-split_num[i-1,2]+quart_half
}}
split_num[partition,1]<-split_num[partition-1,2]+1
split_num[partition,2]<-split_max
```

And, change `foreach` statement.

```
outdata <- foreach(i=1:partition, .combine="rbind", .packages="ff") %dopar% {
   IDs<-subset(persons,personID>=split_num[i,1] & personID<=split_num[i,1])$personID
   for(z in IDs){
     func(data,z)}
}
```

or,

```
outdata <- foreach(i=1:partition, .combine="rbind") %dopar% {
  require(ff) #or require(ffbase)
  IDs<-subset(persons,personID>=split_num[i,1] & personID<=split_num[i,1])$personID
  for(z in IDs){
    func(data,z)}
}
```

Good luck to you.